# GalleryView - JQuery With Landscape and Portrait Photos

Tags: jquery, image

Does anyone have a nice solution for [GalleryView](http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview) when I want to display photos that are a mix of landscapes and portraits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally do this with CSS.  I have a main div that floats left and is sized as needed.  Then, I put the rest of the contents in that div.  You might be able to see what I'm talking about on this article about [an online image thumbnailer](http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.com/2008/12/online-image-thumbnailer.html).  If you find the link to the actual [thumbnailer, you'll see some of the CSS I usually use](http://thumbnailer.netuniverse.com/).

One difference to keep in mind is that in the documentation, I use tables instead of divs ('cause they're easier and I'm lazy and I don't really buy the no tables in HTML thing anymore . . . but that's another thread).  In any event, it works pretty well.  If you need a sample of some css that's more similar to what you're looking for, I can send you more info.

Comment: You shouldn't recommend tables. They are for tabular data. The reason why you don't "buy" the no-more-tables mantra is... well, because you are lazy, you said it. Right now I am redesigning a site and it's being pretty straightforward, I almost don't have to touch the markup, just CSS. I wouldn't try that with tables.

Comment: That may be, but poorly implemented no-tables is as hard to maintain as poorly implemented tables.  Similarly, any HTML with or without tables that's implemented well is easy to maintain.  I'd love to see an example where having tables in your layout implemented in a reasonable way has made it harder to work with.

Comment: What about when you need to rearrange elements and their relative positions?

Comment: In that case, I believe your code will be easier to maintain if you rearrange them in the xhtml/html file as well as update your CSS.  I really hate it when I come behind another developer and I'm trying to figure out why an element is appearing out of place when I expect a specific location based on the DOM only to discover that they're using CSS to specify relative or absolute positions rather than just moving the element in the source (or worse, they're moving it with javascript).

Comment: I don't use absolute position or positioning via JS. That's a bad practice. Anyway, I must agree with something: don't over-engineer and get things done.

Answer (score 0):

When I used it I had to crop the photos to the common size I needed in Photoshop.  You can always add black bars to the photo to keep the ratio.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but handy for those running across this via google (like I did):

GalleryView (at least as of v3.0) has an option on init: panel_scale

From the source:

```
panel_scale: 'crop',            //STRING - cropping option for panel images (crop = scale image and fit to aspect ratio determined by panel_width and panel_height, fit = scale image and preserve original aspect ratio)
```

Setting this to 'fit' allowed for seamless combinations of portrait, landscape and bizarro image dimensions.